# Using checkbox on ModelBuilder tool to control adding to data frame?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder

I have a geodatabase feature class and every day I want to automate the loading of my feature class into a data frame of my map.

At present in my model (below) I add into my data frame the geodatabase feature class 
but I want to add a checkbox option.

i.e. choose whether to add or not the feature class using a checkbox

[image]

This is only part of the tool that I want to do.

This feature class contains reference points for an analysis of service area, which is the reason why I want to automate the data load.

Can I use a checkbox on my tool dialog to control whether, when the model runs, its output feature class gets added to the display (data frame)?

Comment: To try and make what you are asking clear I have made a substantial edit to it.  If I have misunderstood what you were asking then please either improve it by using the edit button or return it to its previous state by using rollback.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a Boolean variable and expose it as a parameter then connect it as a precondition to the Make Feature Layer. This will allow ALL layers to be loaded if TRUE or none of them if FALSE.

[image: Example model of a precondition controlling order of operations]

I don't think you can control each layer as this would require you to interact with the model on every iteration and model builder does not work that way.

Comment: you think it is possible to do this using python script?